# Calling an inherited class method decorator inside child class

Tags: python-3.x

Here I have my Base Class with a fancy decorator:

```py
import functools

class Model:

    def connect(func):
        """Handles opening and closing of connection. Uses functools to preserve docstring of wrapped function."""
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try: 
                #stuff
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            return result
        return wrapper

    @connect
    def get_tables(self):
        """return a list a tables"""
        pass
```

And here is the Child class:

```py
class ChildModel(Model):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])

    @Model.connect
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

It seems I have to call `@Model.connect` instead of just `@connect` otherwise I get `NameError: name 'connect' is not defined`, so is there a way to use just `@connect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, almost since the current scope is just the `globals` ...

you may do:

```
class ChildModel(Model):
    connect = Model.connect
```

another way, you don't have to put connect in `Model`, just make it a global function.

Comment: Yes I saw other people declaring the function outside of a class and I might just do that